# iis show 500 interal server error..while adding 'x-frame-options: deny'

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am facing this issuse. for click jacking I have add 'x-frame-options : deny' in IIS server in hhtp response header but it shows 500 internal error.please tell me if I have to do more change in in IIS or any other solution.

Comment: You need to view the exception message and stack trace behind the 500 error.

Comment: Please refer [Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) and [Mitigating framesniffing with the X-Frame-Options header](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2694329).

Comment: nothing worthy...please give me solution